# Restore eth2 interface?

Tags: centos, ethernet

i have centos 5, i have used "ifconfig eth2 down" and the server gets unaccesible, i can access to the files only at the moment, so i cant use "ifconfig eth2 up" to restore it, wich files have i to edit to restore it?

Regards

Comment: You're hosed.  There's no file you can frob to get the ethernet to come back up.  However, if you didn't do anything to your sysconfig, just reboot it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by "access to the files only", but that interface should be defined by /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth2 script, hope this is what you were asking about.